# Catching a converted temporary by reference, on all three major implementations

Tags: c++, exception, language-lawyer

I'm confused by all three mainstream compilers/runtimes' handling of this C++ code ([Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/eehczqvTM)):

```
int main() {
    int i = 42;
    try {
        throw &i;
    } catch (void*&) {
        puts("incorrectly hit?");
    } catch (...) {}
    try {
        throw nullptr;
    } catch (void*&) {
        puts("incorrectly hit?");
    } catch (...) {}
}
```

Note that the "exception object" being thrown here is an object of type `int*` resp. `std::nullptr_t`. But the object being caught is of type `void*`. The only way this can work is for the runtime to create a temporary `void*` converted from the type of the exception object, right? So the `void*&` in the catch-handler must refer to a temporary, and not to the actual in-flight exception object?

Looking closer at the wording, [[except.handle]](https://eel.is/c++draft/except.handle) says:

> A *handler* is a match for an exception object of type `E` if
>
> - The *handler* is of type `cv T` or `cv T&` and `E` and `T` are the same type (ignoring the top-level cv-qualifiers), or
> - the *handler* is of type `cv T` or `cv T&` and `T` is an unambiguous public base class of `E`, or
> - the *handler* is of type `cv T` or `const T&` where `T` is a pointer or pointer-to-member type and `E` is a pointer or pointer-to-member type that can be converted to `T` by [...] a standard pointer conversion [...], or
> - the *handler* is of type `cv T` or `const T&` where `T` is a pointer or pointer-to-member type and `E` is `std​::​nullptr_t`.

None of these bullet points seem to apply. So are all three vendors simply *wrong* in allowing this `catch` handler to be hit? The [except.handle] wording isn't new; it was touched as recently as 2016 ([CWG2093](https://cplusplus.github.io/CWG/issues/2093.html)), but seems to have been introduced as a result of [CWG388](https://cplusplus.github.io/CWG/issues/388.html) & [CWG729](https://cplusplus.github.io/CWG/issues/729.html) circa 2012.

The resolution of 388 says "This resolution would require an ABI change"; does that mean that all three vendors simply never bothered to implement it?

(Updated to add: [[except.handle]/15](https://eel.is/c++draft/except.handle#15) says: "When the handler declares a reference to an object, any changes to the referenced object are changes to the exception object and will have effect should that object be rethrown" — but that's obviously not true when the reference binds to a converted temporary. I think that sentence could be rescued by adding the adjective "non-const" before "reference.")

Comment: @user12002570: That question asks why `throw T()` conformingly matches `catch (T&)` (with the same type `T` in both cases); this question asks why `throw T()` non-conformingly matches `catch (U&)` (where `U` is a pointer type convertible from `T` but otherwise unrelated, e.g. `T` is `std::nullptr_t` and `U` is `int*`).

Comment: Clang and GCC diverge in allowing one to modify the temporary inside `catch (void*& p)`: https://godbolt.org/z/hbjjdrbfM